# Correct way to stop asynchronous ISearchJob

Tags: c++, winapi, com, updates, wuapi

I am going to use [WUA API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099(v=vs.85).aspx) and begin execution of an asynchronous search for updates in this way:

```
CComPtr<SearchCallbackImpl> iscc_; <<-- Note you need to CreateInstance
CComPtr<ISearchJob> pUpJob_;
pUpJob_ = NULL;

pUpSearcher_->BeginSearch(
        CComVariant(criteria.c_str()).bstrVal,
        iscc_,
        CComVariant(L"Scanning"),
        &pUpJob_);
```

When I need to stop my program, but [ISearchJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386070(v=vs.85).aspx)  has not completed yet, I use this code:

```
if (pUpJob_)
{
    CComVariant isStopped;
    pUpJob_->get_IsCompleted(&isStopped.boolVal);
    if (isStopped.boolVal == VARIANT_FALSE)
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(pUpJob_->RequestAbort()))
        {
            pUpJob_->CleanUp();
            pUpJob_.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Generally this code works but sometime it hangs on `pUpJob_->CleanUp();` and I do not have ability to stop my programm correctly.

So my questions are:

1. What is the correct way to stop [asynchronous search job for updates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386070(v=vs.85).aspx)?
2. Also i misunderstood what is difference between [ISearchJob::CleanUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386072(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ISearchJob::RequestAbort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386076(v=vs.85).aspx) and how to use this methods to stop asynchronous search correctly?
3. Should this methods be used together or separately?

Answer (score 1):

`RequestAbort()` is also asynchronous (the hint to that is in the name). After calling it, you should call `pUpSearcher_->EndSearch()`; it will return an ISearchResult with `ResultCode` equal to `orcAborted` if the abort was successful. *Then* you can free your resources.

I'm not fully sure how `CleanUp()` is supposed to be used, but [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385820(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to imply it's intended for scripts that have callbacks, and that you're not supposed to call `CleanUp()` from within a callback. Not sure where your code for cancelling is run.

Comment: I use this code in destructor of my class, which wraps WUAPI.

Comment: What will be if I will do only `pUpJob_->RequestAbort()` without `pUpSearcher_->EndSearch()`

Comment: @SpaceRabbit just curious what was your resolution to this situation? My algorithm does this when the search needs to be aborted due to program exiting: (1) BeginSearch (2) RequestAbort (3) Cleanup (4) NO EndSearch. The problem is sometimes Cleanup() crashes! I wonder if you even need to call Cleanup at all when RequestAbort is used?

Comment: @SpaceRabbit would be great if you share your final resolution to this issue here in this thread, as I am running into a similar issue now. But in my case CleanUp() crashes!